# No response after sending json data from browser to Django view with ajax POST

Tags: json, ajax, django, post

I am using handsontable to simulate a spreadsheet on my web application.  I want to send the json data that the user enters into the spreadsheet to my database.

Html button:

```
<button id="send_post" class="btn size-medium bg-green text-white shadow hover-moveup">Send Post Request</button>
```

Js:

```
document.getElementById("send_post").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token },
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify(hot.getSourceData()),
      statusCode: {
        200: function (your_Response_Data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(hot.getSourceData()))
        },
        // ... handle errors if required
        404: function () {
        }
      },
      complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
      }
    });


  })
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
    user_id = request.user
    if request.is_ajax():

        if request.method == "POST":
            received_json_data = json.loads(request.body)

            return HttpResponse(received_json_data, content_type="application/json")
```

Terminal:

```
[04/Apr/2019 01:19:23] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

I receive the data in my view, but Httpresponse is not returning the data back to the browser.

Comment: I think the problem might be ```request.is_ajax()```, try removing that line to see if you get a response.

Comment: Still doesn't respond on the browser.  I also tried changing HttpResponse to redirect('/') but still nothing.
I can print the received_json_data and it shows up in my terminal, so I know it is getting to that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting location.href upon a successful POST request

```
statusCode: {
        200: function (your_Response_Data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(hot.getSourceData()));
            location.href = "/";
        },
```